# Convert tensorflow gpu model to cpu for inference

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have TensorFlow pre-trained weights for inference. When I install `tensorflow-gpu==2.2.0` I got the result. But when I install `tensorflow-cpu==2.2.0`, I got `nan`. I want to host the model online on a cpu, so what should I do.
This is how I load model

```
model = Model()
model.load_weights('weights.hdf5')
model.predict()
```

Comment: There is no conversion required. If it works in GPU then it should also works in CPU. Can you share standalone code to replicate your issue? so that we can try to help you. Thanks!

Comment: please check this [colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16RbTjME6LcGjG7uSOSr5f8KQMXBH65WZ?usp=sharing)

Comment: if you run it on colab with cpu it would not work. but with gpu it will work